Water pressure in my house drops about 20 to 30 psi when a second faucet is turned on?
Plumbing in the house is 2 year old and using a water pressure regulator. Municipal water line has 160 psi and regulator is set to 70 psi.

It has always been this way, or it has changed recently? Please [edit] the question to clarify that.

Somewhere in the system there is a restriction.
That could be the regulator itself, if it's not large enough to support two faucets at once, or if it has been obstructed by debris (such as old pipe corrosion or mineral encrustation that has broken off and flowed with the water) from the water supply system.
It could be debris in the strainer/filter that's frequently associated with such regulators (to prevent their internal ports from becoming clogged, hopefully), if that hasn't been cleaned out recently.
It could be a partially closed valve. Or one partially plugged with debris not caught by a filter upstream.
It could be a separate filter that's in need of a media change and restricting flow.

When I had this problem, it was a ~5/8 in pebble trapped against the regulator strainer, along with a a bunch of smaller sediment.  I was amazed by how large of a rock had made its way down the water line!  Fortunately in my case there was a union in front of the regulator so this was relatively easy to diagnose/fix.
